# Trying to hover over an element with selenium python

Tags: python, html, selenium, google-chrome, firefox

I am trying to hover over "Device" to click the next button which is "Active Monitor Availability". "Device" is nested under a tab named "ANALYZE".

The code that I've tried:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'ANALYZE')]").click()
time.sleep(3)
device=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[normalize-space()='Device']"
achains = ActionChains(driver)
achains.move_to_element(device).perform
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[normalize-space()='Active Monitor Availability']").click
```

Current error:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //span[normalize-space()='Active Monitor Availability']

Does this mean that selenium has hover over the wrong place?

I have tried hover manually to "Device" and it works.

HTML Example:

```html
<div class="x-menu-item x-menu-item-main x-box-item" style="width: 240px; left: 0px; top: 120px; margin: 0px;" role="presentation" id="menuitem-1483" data-testid="device" xpath="1"><a id="menuitem-1483-itemEl" data-ref="itemEl" class="x-menu-item-link" href="#" hidefocus="true" unselectable="on" role="menuitem" aria-hidden="false" aria-disabled="false" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="menu-1484" data-componentid="menuitem-1483" tabindex="0"
    style=""><span id="menuitem-1483-textEl" data-ref="textEl" class="x-menu-item-text x-menu-item-text-main x-menu-item-indent-right-arrow" unselectable="on" role="presentation">Device</span><div role="presentation" id="menuitem-1483-arrowEl" data-ref="arrowEl" class="x-menu-item-arrow x-menu-item-arrow-main"></div></a></div>
```

Edit: I have added the whole HTML file to Pastebin

Link: https://pastebin.com/rLf5qvej

Password: StackOverflow123

FYI the id is dynamic.

Thanks Everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the limited html provided try the following by amending the xpath from:

```
"//span[normalize-space()='Device']"
```

to:

```
"//div[@data-testid='device']//a[@data-ref='textEl']//span[normalize-space(text())='Device']"
```

or

Comment: Hi... I tried your code but get an error instead, Error code: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //div[@data-testid='device']//a[@data-ref='textEl']//span[normalize-space(text())='Device']

Comment: I have added whole html code to pastebin, Link: https://pastebin.com/rLf5qvej

Password: StackOverflow123

Comment: I'll try an have a look soon, in the mean time can you try path with just ```//span[normalize-space(text())='Device']```

Comment: Hi... I get the same error code as before by using this code, Error code: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //span[normalize-space()='Active Monitor Availability']